# Import third-party libraries to Angular Library gives error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

Trying to create library using ng-packagr.

Inside project I run :

ng g library nt-select --prefix nt

inside nt-select.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nt-nt-select',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [placeholder]="placeholder" [disabled]="disabled" [multiple]="multiple" [(ngModel)]="value"
                  [required]="required">

        <ngx-mat-select-search *ngIf="searchable"
                               [formControl]="optionFilterCtrl"
                               [placeholderLabel]="'Axtar'"
                               [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'Tapılmadı'"
                               [clearSearchInput]="false"
        ></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="opt.value">
          {{opt.label}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

      <mat-error>{{getErrors('hobbies')}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

  `,
  styles: []
})
export class NtSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and nt.select.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NtSelectComponent } from './nt-select.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material';
import {NgxMatSelectSearchModule} from 'ngx-mat-select-search';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    NgxMatSelectSearchModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [NtSelectComponent],
  exports: [NtSelectComponent]
})
export class NtSelectModule { }
```

The problem is nt-select emits error cannot find name of **mat-form-field, mat-select, ngx-mat-select-search**  even though I imported all modules. 
Following tutorial on : https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5 
What might be issue ? 
 thanks in advance

Comment: did you have to add anything to the package.json for your library? wonder because i am having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include angular material and other external packages in your `ng-package.json` file

```
{
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
    "externals": {
      "@angular/material/input": "ng.material.input",
      "@angular/material/select": "ng.material.select"
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much! It solved the issue. Could you please tell me where I get information about this ? It worked but I have no idea why third-party libraries are imported in this way especially angular material.